# How to cope-up with this security flaw in Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, photos, lock-screen, security

As we all know, Windows 10 Mobile has new security bug can let anyone bypass the code and access the photos in the gallery even when the phone is locked by following procedure.

1. Switch on the camera while the device is still locked using the
   camera shortcut on the lock screen
2. Capture a photo and open it using the little thumbnail in the left lower corner.
3. Post opening the pic, delete it using the trash bin icon on the
   screen and press the back button on your Windows phone.
4. The thumbnail will turn into black icon. Tap it to preview a photo.
5. Press the back button and try to open the picture again using the
   same black icon on the left.
6. The third time you do that, you would be able to access the entire photo gallery on the Windows phone.

I can't even find an app that can keep photos locked. So my question is that is there anyway that I can control unauthorized access to photos?

**EDIT:** Perhaps I was unable to convey my message, infact I'm very bad at academic writing. Well incase of any confusion, see these relevant articles:

1. http://news.softpedia.com/news/windows-10-mobile-security-bug-allows-hackers-to-bypass-passcode-access-photos-512904.shtml
2. http://windowsreport.com/windows-10-mobile-security-bugs/

Comment: Have you reported this bug to Microsoft?

Comment: Nope.......should I use Feedback hub for this?

Comment: That would be a good start. Although when I tried to reproduce the issue, I don't see the black thumbnail you refer to in step 4

Comment: @RowlandShaw perhaps I'm a bit unclear..... but now I've added links. 
Please have a look on these.

Comment: From what I understood this was fixed in both the Slow and Fast rings. Are you sure about your info?

Comment: Maybe it has fixed now. I don't remember exact build no. but when I checked it was'nt........I have cut down the contridictry part

Comment: Well @RareNCool .....whether fixed in internal rings or not ......... I think non-insiders should also have a solution besides waiting or joining either rings.

Comment: I don't see the issue with the current generally available build, so this looks like a lot of noise about an issue that no longer exists?

Comment: @RowlandShaw the bug is already reported to Microsoft in feedback hub. Please visit the first link. Well I'll close the question if nobody seems to have same issue.

Comment: This doesn't sound [on-topic](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), as it doesn't sound like a "question based on actual problems that you face"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are pointing to has already been fixed by Microsoft. Here is the link to the corresponding [feedback](https://aka.ms/Aip501) in Feedback Hub. Below is the Microsoft's response to the feedback

> This problem should be fixed in Windows Insiders build 15025 and
>   later. If you are still seeing the issue, please go to Settings -
>   System - About - More Info and confirm your build number

---

In case of future events like this,

1. Go to feedback Hub and search for feedback on same problem and upvote it.
2. If no feedback is found create a new one.
3. Stay on the latest update.

Comment: Ohk.........When I checked on fast ring it was perhaps 15021. Then I downgraded my phone and updated it to non-insider build. Well Thanks

Comment: @User5 You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You asked, "How do I cope with this".  My answer is that you first report the issues, and then ensure you regularly update your phone.

I believe the issue has been fixed.  I could not reproduce this using my stock Lumia 950.

Answer (score 0):

There are media locking apps in the store.  For example Brilli Gallery Locker or File Locker Free.